# Get value between 2nd and 3rd comma

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I am trying to extract the state from an address where everything is in one column, heres an example:

```
2901 MAIN ST,CORNING,NY,14830
```

I have been trying to figure out how to do it with the `substr` and `instr` together, but I cant seem to get the hang of `instr`. Here is what I have so far:

```
select substr('hello,hello,NY,11725-1234',1,instr('hello,hello,NY,11725-1234',',',2,3))
from dual;
```

I thought it would start at the second comma and end at the 3rd and get my everything in between, but that doesnt seem to be the case.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
  regexp_substr('2901 MAIN ST,CORNING,NY,14830', '(.*?,){2}(.*?),', 1, 1, '', 2) 
from dual
```

In general,

```
n_th_component := 
  regexp_substr(string, '(.*?,){'||(n-1)||'}([^,]*)', 1, 1, '', 2);
```

Example:

```
select 
  n,  
  regexp_substr('2901 MAIN ST,CORNING,NY,14830', 
                '(.*?,){'||(n-1)||'}([^,]*)', 1, 1, '', 2)
from (select level n from dual connect by level <= 4)
```

Comment: As much as I would like to accept something that works, I have no idea what this does and it wouldnt help me in the future. Is there anyway you can explain what this is doing?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try and decipher the syntax from the site you linked. I also assume RTFM stands for Read The F**** Manual, if you dont like helping people then you should stay off this site. I came here after reading that link and still couldnt get what I needed.

Comment: @user2405778, while I also find the F bit offensive, I also recognise that RTFM is merely the standard way of saying "read this first". If Egor wanted to offend you, he wouldn't have linked to the relevant documentation. After having read the doc, you could have then said "ok, I read the link, but I don't understand x, y, z" - all the while remembering that we are all unpaid volunteers here, and we love helping people, but we are not your personal tutor.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - RTFM is always offensive because it is always dismissive of the person to whom it is directed.  In some ways it is even ruder when it is attached to a relevant URL.  If we've taken that about of trouble, why not expend a little energy typing something less harsh than *RTFM* ?

Comment: I guess I like to assume the best of others :) I prefer to read it as "Read This First, Mate" :)

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions are a great way to do this sort of thing. SUBSTR and INSTR can also be used, however, by taking advantage of the 4th parameter of INSTR, `nth_appearance`:

```
select INSTR(mystring,',',1,1) AS first_comma
      ,INSTR(mystring,',',1,2) AS second_comma
      ,SUBSTR(mystring
             ,INSTR(mystring,',',1,1) + 1
             ,INSTR(mystring,',',1,2)
              - INSTR(mystring,',',1,1)
              - 1)
       AS middle_bit
FROM
(select 'hello,world,NY,11725-1234' as mystring from dual);

FIRST_COMMA  SECOND_COMMA  MIDDLE_BIT
===========  ============  ==========
          6            12  world
```