# Ruby: extract substring between 2nd and 3rd fullstops

Tags: ruby, string, truncate

i am constructing a program in Ruby which requires the value to be extracted between the 2nd and 3rd full-stop in a string.

I have searched online for various related solutions, including truncation and this prior Stack-Overflow question: [Get value between 2nd and 3rd comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795794/get-value-between-2nd-and-3rd-comma), however no answer illustrated a solution in the Ruby language.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How about, posting a file which shows the problem and your tries to solve it?

Comment: This question seems to either require *us* to write the code for you, or to recommend a site or book you can copy code from. Both those are off-topic here on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = my_string.split(".")
list[2]
```

That will do it I think. First command splits it into a list. Second gets the bit you want

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string on [full stops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop) (aka periods), but that creates an array with one element for each substring preceding a full stop. If the document had, say, one million such substrings, that would be a rather inefficient way of getting just the third one.

Suppose the string is:

```
mystring =<<_
Now is the time
for all Rubiests
to come to the
aid of their
bowling team.
Or their frisbee
team. Or their
air guitar team.
Or maybe something
else...
_
```

Here are a couple of approaches you could take.

**#1 Use a regular expression**

```
r = /
    (?:      # start a non-capture group
      .*?\.  # match any character any number of times, lazily, followed by a full stop
    ){2}     # end non-capture group and perform operation twice
    \K       # forget everything matched before
    [^.]*    # match everything up to the next full stop
    /xm      # extended/free-spacing regex definition mode and multiline mode

mystring[r]
  #=> " Or their\nair guitar team"
```

You could of course write the regex:

```
r = /(?:.*?\.){2}\K[^.]*/m
```

but the extended form makes it self-documenting.

The regex engine will step through the string until it finds a match or concludes that there can be no match, and stop there.

**#2 Pretend a full stop is a newline**

First suppose we were looking for the third line, rather than the third substring followed by a full stop. We could write:

```
mystring.each_line.take(3).last.chomp
  # => "to come to the"
```

[Enumerable#take](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) determines when a line ends by examining the *input record separator*, which is held by the [global variable](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Global_Variables) `$/`. By default, `$/` equals a newline. We therefore could do this:

```
irs = $/  # save old value, normally \n
$/ = '.'
mystring.each_line.take(3).last[0..-2]
  #=> " Or their\nair guitar team"
```

Then leave no footprints:

```
$/ = irs
```

Here [String#each_line](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-each_line) returns an enumerator (in effect, a rule for determining a sequence of values), not an array.

Comment: The OP's delimiter is a full stop, not a newline.

Comment: BTW, what is a “fullstop” outside of F1 races?

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. It's fixed. I think. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯