# Need to extract a string from a filename

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in a staging table where i am inserting the filenames. The format for the filename is as follows:

```
T225674_<suppliercode><YYYYMMDD>-<HHMM>_**<TIMBE NUMBER>**.in
```

Example:

```
T225674_789020161010-0900_12345.in
```

(I need to extract 12345 from the above string, the string can be anything and of whatever length)

I need to extract `<TIMBE NUMBER>` from the above filename, could you please let us know how to do it in Oracle SQL.

Thanks

Comment: How is this question too broad?

Comment: Why don't you try substring like this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412898/split-string-and-take-last-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there's a regexp that does this but that's not my strongest point. However, a combination of instr and substr will get you there:

```
substr(string, instr(string, '_', -1) + 1, instr(string, '.') - instr(string, '_', -1) - 1))
```

Comment: Even the best regexp solution (which has not been proposed yet) will be slower than using `instr` and `substr`. regexp solutions should be used only when a simple solution with `instr` and `substr` is not available. A nitpick here though: I would also use the `-1` third argument to search for the period (just in case there may be other periods in the string, for example in the supplier code).

Answer (score 1):

@Rene answers it perfectly, but for completeness here is a Regex_substr solution.

An altered version of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17796024/3240704).

```
    select 
            regexp_substr('T225674_789020161010-0900_12345.in', '(.*?_){2}(.*?)\.', 1, 1, '', 2) 
    from dual
```

`(.*?_){2}` - Anything after the second underscore

`(.*?)\.'`  - Anything before a decimal point

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For even more completeness (winking at user3240704), here is a much simpler and more efficient regexp solution. Even this will be slower than Rene's solution.

Using the info the OP provided: the number to be searched for is preceded by underscore and followed by the exact string `'.in'` (if that information is incorrect, then the solution will fail).

```
select regexp_substr(input_string, '_(\d+)\.in$', 1, 1, null, 1) from....
```

This will search for underscore, followed by one or more digits (\d means digit, + means one or more), followed by period (escaped: . because in a regular expression . by itself means "any character), followed by 'in', followed by the end of string - so the search pattern is anchored at the end of the input string.

Putting `\d+` in parentheses makes it a "subexpression" which can be referred to in the `regexp_substr()` function. The sixth argument, 1, means "return the substring that is the first subexpression from the matched substring."

Comment: Very nice piece of code. The answer is surely now "complete" ;)

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `regexp_replace`:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(a,'(T225674_.*_)(.*)(\.in)' ,'\2') from (
  select 'T225674_789020161010-0900_12345.in' a from dual
)
```

First part `(T225674_.*_)` matches anything starting with `T225674_`, ending with `_`. then leave space for what comes next, until the ending group `(.in)`: this is the purpose of second group `(.*)`.

With `regexp_replace`, you can play with the content of the matched groups. Here I only print content of group n°2 with `\2`.