# Using REGEXP_SUBSTR to get certain string

Tags: oracle, substr

I have trouble of getting the following Numbers only from the given string:

Taid-HP- VSAT -100021258856985847585 - BMN

I want the result to be

100021258856985847585

I used teh REGEXP in all ways but i could not

Comment: what is the format? String between 3rd and 4th `-` ?

Comment: How close did you get - what was your best attempt? Also how rigid is the format of the values you have to parse?

Comment: There are at least three possible interpretations of your requirement, all equally valid and all consistent with your example. You need to be much more "deterministic" (precise) with your requirements. The possible interpretations: (1) everything between the third and the fourth dash; (2) the string of digits (there is one in each string), regardless of position within the string; (3) the string after `VSAT -` and up to the next dash, regardless of position within the string. How are **we** supposed to know which is the correct one?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt support. i want to have the string of digits  (i.e. 100021258856985847585) wherever it was its location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want string between 3rd and 4th `-`, use this

```
select trim(regexp_substr(str, '(.*?-){3}(.*?)-', 1, 1, '', 2)) from
(select 'Taid-HP- VSAT -100021258856985847585 - BMN' as str from dual)
```

Referred this answer 
[Get value between 2nd and 3rd comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795794/get-value-between-2nd-and-3rd-comma)