# ORACLE:SQL REGEXP_SUBSTR that returns the column value between 1st semicolon and second one. Also other value after last semi clumn

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

varchar: BLAH:123:678

need value between first semi column and second one: 123
need value after last semi column: 678

Comment: have you tried INSTR?, instr from reverse to get from right and instr to get from left, this if you don't want to code the length

Comment: What have you tried? There are some good posts which are quite similar like this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795794/get-value-between-2nd-and-3rd-comma.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you always have exactly two `':'`, this is solution without regexp, maybe not so elegant at first sight, but faster than regexp:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(
              yourString,
                INSTR(yourString, ':') + 1,
                INSTR(yourString,':', 1, 2 )
                  - INSTR(yourString, ':') - 1
             ),
       SUBSTR(
              yourString,
              INSTR(yourString, ':', 1, 2) +1
             )
  FROM (SELECT 'BLAH:123:678' AS yourString FROM DUAL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below regex:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('BLAH:123:678', ':(\d+):', 1, 1, NULL, 1) first_val,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR ('BLAH:123:678', '(\d+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) second_val
  FROM DUAL
```

Output:

```
first_Val  second_val
123        678
```